# HTML Center Widget

Tags: html, widget, center

Hi I have the following code of a social media bar:

```
<span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_hcount' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_hcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>
```

I want proper space and horizontal align for these Social bars. These bars should positioned to center of my window.

Can someone help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

make to divs arround, the first has a width:100% and position:absolute. the secvomd inside and arround all spans has the width:300px (or as much as needed and margin:10px auto; the 10px is top and bottom auto is for left and right. you can also try margin:10px auto 20px auto; and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You have got to add a wrapper to it. Let say you should have:

```
<div id="social-bar">
   <span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
   <span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
   <span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
   <span class='st_linkedin_hcount' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
   <span class='st_pinterest_hcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
   <span class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>
</div>
```

From there you could make a CSS style like this:

```
#social-bar {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center; /* to enforce its child elements to the center */
}

#social-bar span {
   padding-right: 20px;
}
```